# How can we add confidence intervals to plots of effects from multinomial logistic regression models in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, logistic-regression, confidence-interval

I need to add confidence intervals (or eyes) to a plot of the effect(s) of multinomial logistic regression models.

Here is a toy reproducible example of the kinds of data, logit model, and plot I am working with:

```
install.packages("effects")
library("effects")
ToyData2 <- data.table(Answer = c("Remained incorrect", "Changed to correct", "Changed to correct", "Remained incorrect",
                             "Remained correct", "Changed to incorrect", "Remained correct", "Changed to correct",
                             "Changed to correct", "Changed to incorrect", "Remained incorrect", "Remained incorrect",
                             "Remained correct", "Changed to incorrect", "Remained correct", "Changed to correct"),
                   Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                           "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", NA, "Male", "Female", "Male"),
                   Education = c("Less than Bachelors", "Less than Bachelors", "Bachelors",NA,
                                 "Post Bachelors","Post Bachelors","Bachelors", "Less than Bachelors",
                                 "Bachelors",NA,"Post Bachelors","Post Bachelors",
                                 "Post Bachelors", "Less than Bachelors", "Bachelors","Post Bachelors"),
                   Minutes = c(1, 5, 1, 29, NA, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4),
                   Problem = c("A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B", "C","C","C","C", "D","D","D","D"))
ToyData2

ToyData2$Answer <- factor(ToyData2$Answer, ordered = FALSE)
summary(ToyData2$Answer)
ToyData2$Answer <- relevel(ToyData2$Answer, ref = 'Changed to incorrect')

ToyData2$Education <- factor(ToyData2$Education, levels = c("Less than Bachelors","Bachelors","Post Bachelors"))

ToyOutcomeLogit <- multinom(Answer ~ Sex + Education + Minutes + Problem, data = ToyData2)
summary(ToyOutcomeLogit)
table(ToyData2$Minutes)
plot(Effect('Minutes', ToyOutcomeLogit), multiline=T)
table(ToyData2$Education)
plot(Effect('Sex', ToyOutcomeLogit), multiline=T)
```

Here are the plots that are produced by lines that begin with "plot":

1. Effect of time (Minutes)[image]
2. Effect of (Bachelors) education[image]

Here are some of the libraries I am using (in the rest of my R file) in case you need them:

```
library('pacman')
p_load(
  'data.table',
  'DescTools',
  'effects',
  'ggpubr',
  'ggsignif',
  'glue',
  'Hmisc',
  'irr',
  'lm.beta',
  'nnet',
  'openxlsx',
  'psych',
  'scales',
  'sjPlot',
  'stats',
  'tidyr',
  'tidyverse'
)
```

**How can get confidence intervals on plots like these?** Or, more specifically:

**A. How can I tweak the existing code to add confidence intervals?**

**B. What other functions could  I use to plot these effects *with confidence intervals*?**

**C. What other *package's* functions should I use?**

(Note: I am currently running R 4.2.2 in case that is relevant.)

Comment: Your data sample is insufficient to generate confidence intervals for the type of plot you want. Could you perhaps supply a substantially longer version so that we can demonstrate a method? Thanks

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron. I have doubled the number of datapoints and replotted them. Would this be sufficient (even if the CIs are not that informative for the toy example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently replacing `multiline=T` with `confint=T` in the plot command will add CIs—bands or bars.

**Bands:**[image]

**Bars**:[image]

Alas, I have not found out how to add CIs to the collapsed multiline plot itself.